# Image src with special characters

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my images not being displayed when they have a # or % symbol.

I am using PHP to read a directory and display all images but any with those symbols just have broken links. The images are uploaded to the server fine but wont display.

Comment: Tried to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on those image names?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to write a function which replaces the % and # characters with their corresponding url-encoding symbols, you can find a reference here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

you should compare the output of your script to the directory list you get for that dir in your browser, then you will obviously see the correct mapping for your special chars.

are you uploading images via php? then you could maybe map special chars to spaces or dashes. don't think having special chars in file names is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Best will be to strip out all those characters before uploading the images. (If you are using FTP, rename your files. If you are using PHP to upload, write a function which does it)

Otherwise you will need to escape the symbols: Take a look at [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Cant rename the images there are 1000's and from multiple clients. Cheers

Comment: So they are using FTP to upload them? But you could write a little script doing it for you. Maybe you can cronjob this script